# Trying to merge a linked list in descending order

Tags: c, algorithm, merge, linked-list

So I have two linked lists with my own Node implementation being the Linked list. For some reason I have the code that merges both lists in place that should add the least value and then move down both lists, consistently checking which one is least and adding it to the new list. For some reason my code merges both lists but not in ascending order.

```
/*
Takes two lists and merges them without creating extra nodes. */
Node *merge(Node* list1, Node* list2) {
    Node *mergelist, *cur1, *cur2, *curm, *prevm;

    cur1 = list1, cur2 = list2;
    mergelist = NULL;

    while (cur1 != NULL || cur2 != NULL) {
        // List2:node < List1:node
        if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur2->value < cur1->value) {
            curm = cur2;
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List2:node <= List1:node
        else if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur1->value <= cur2->value) {
            curm = cur1;
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List2: have remaining nodes, List1: not
        else if (cur2 != NULL && cur1 == NULL) {
            curm = cur2;
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List1: have remaining nodes, List2: not
        else if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 == NULL) {
            curm = cur1;
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // check if mergelist is empty 
        // add current node as first node to it
        if (mergelist == NULL) {
            mergelist = curm;
            prevm = mergelist;
        }
        // add current node to the tail of new merged list
        else {
            prevm->next = curm;
            prevm = prevm->next;
        }
    }

    //Sort list

    return mergelist;
}
```

Example:

```
MERGE TEST
List 1: 9 9 5 5 3 3
List 2: 10 10 6 6 1 1
List 1 + 2 Merged:
Merged list: 9 9 5 5 3 3 10 10 6 6 1 1
```

It is merging the lists side by side and not in ascending order. Any ideas why? 

EDIT: I cannot use nested loops. Only one loop may be present.

Comment: Well the lists can contain anything, they just happen to be descending. So I don't want to traverse them in a certain order. I just want something like: if(list1<list) { add list1 to new list} else{ add list2 to new list}, and continue that until both lists are empty

Comment: Your algorithm just did exactly that actually?

Comment: Well I am running tests, so I just happened to make those two lists in that order, but really the  inputs could be anything for example like in below comments, list1=[1,3,5,7,9] and list2=[2,4,6,8], then result list should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: If the input lists are `[4, 1]` and `[3, 2]`. Do you want the result `[3,2,4,1]` or `[1,2,3,4]` or `[4,3,2,1]`?

Comment: if input lists are [4,1] and [3,2] id like the output to be [1,2,3,4]

Comment: that's the main issue i think, if the input lists were in order, then no problem, I could just traverse them in reverse, but this isnt the case.

Comment: I this case your algorithm is entirely wrong. You used a list merge, this will only output a fully sorted list if you input a fully sorted list (in correct order).

Comment: The best option you have is using your algorithm, but pre sorting both lists. Runtime complexity will scale better than merging and then sorting.

Comment: ok ill try that out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only use your merging algorithm when lists are sorted. This should also be the best option you have, sort then merge. It has better runtimecomplexity than merge then sort. So keep your algorithm but add sorting to it. Pay attention to the correct sort order. (In your example the sort order was flipped).

But aside from that, you shouldn't use the mergeList as you do in the end of your loop. Instead construct the List directly. See the code:

```
/*
Takes two lists and merges them without creating extra nodes. */
Node *merge(Node* list1, Node* list2) {
    Node *mergelist, *cur1, *cur2, *curm, *prevm;
    cur1 = list1, cur2 = list2;
    curm = mergelist;

    while (cur1 != NULL || cur2 != NULL) {
        if ((cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur2->value < cur1->value) || (cur2 != NULL && cur1 == NULL)) {
            curm->next = cur2;
            curm = curm->next;
            cur2 = cur2->next;

        } else if ((cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur1->value <= cur2->value) || (cur1 != NULL && cur2 == NULL)) {
            curm->next = cur1;
            curm = curm->next;
            cur1 = cur1->next;
        }
    }
    return mergelist->next;
}
```

Comment: What is this mergelist = new Node(); ? can you do that in C? I have already initialized a mergelist above using Node* mergelist;

Comment: sorry, my mistake, ignore that line, haha. I corrected :)

Comment: Ok, I tried that code, which ended in a Segmentation core dump

Comment: You still have to reverse the order of your input lists. If there is an error in my code, I'm sorry, I have handwritten in without an IDE. But you should get the idea.

Comment: What will reversing the lists do, for example input lists could be as follows:

Comment: list1=[1,3,5,7,9] and list2=[2,4,6,8], then result list should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: Pretty much, the two input lists could be in any order, and the output list needs to be in ascending order.

Comment: Ok so actually, I misread my assignment. The two input lists will be in ascending order. So the output should also be ascending. How would I go about that

Comment: I this case flip the conditions to always add the greater element of the two. This should do fine. I update my answer. Please accept the answer (green arrow) if it solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My original code worked fine after tweaking input lists. Thanks everyone. @A1m

```
/*
Takes two lists and merges them without creating extra nodes. */
Node *merge(Node* list1, Node* list2) {
    Node *mergelist, *cur1, *cur2, *curm, *prevm;
    cur1 = list1, cur2 = list2;
    curm = mergelist;

     cur1 = list1, cur2 = list2;
    mergelist = NULL;

    while (cur1 != NULL || cur2 != NULL) {
        // List2:node < List1:node
        if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur2->value < cur1->value) {
            curm = cur2;
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List2:node <= List1:node
        else if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL && cur1->value <= cur2->value) {
            curm = cur1;
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List2: have remaining nodes, List1: not
        else if (cur2 != NULL && cur1 == NULL) {
            curm = cur2;
            cur2 = cur2->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // List1: have remaining nodes, List2: not
        else if (cur1 != NULL && cur2 == NULL) {
            curm = cur1;
            cur1 = cur1->next;
            curm->next = NULL;
        }

        // check if mergelist is empty 
        // add current node as first node to it
        if (mergelist == NULL) {
            mergelist = curm;
            prevm = mergelist;
        }
        // add current node to the tail of new merged list
        else {
            prevm->next = curm;
            prevm = prevm->next;
        }
    }

    return mergelist;
}
```

Test Output:

```
##############
MERGE TEST
List 1: list: 1 1 3 3 5 5 9 9
List 2: list: 2 2 6 6 8 8 8 8
List 1 + 2 Merged:
Merged list: 1 1 2 2 3 3 5 5 6 6 8 8 8 8 9 9
##############
MERGE TEST 2
List 3:list: 1 1 2 2 3 3 5 5 6 6 8 8 8 8 9 9
List 4:list: 1 3 9 12
List 3 + List 4 Merged:
list: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 6 6 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 12
##############
```

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Take into account that your approach of comparing values of the two lists makes sense only in case when the both lists are sorted in the descending order provided that you want to get a sorted list in the ascending order. Otherwise there is no sense to compare values of two nodes of the lists.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node * merge( Node *list1, Node *list2 )
{
    Node *mergelist = NULL;

    while ( list1 || list2 )
    {

        _Bool second = ( list1 == NULL ) || 
                       ( list2 != NULL && list1->value < list2->value );

        Node *current;

        if ( second )
        {
            current = list2;
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
        else
        {
            current = list1;
            list1 = list1->next;
        }

        current->next = mergelist;
        mergelist = current;
    }

    return mergelist;
}

void display( Node *list )
{
    for ( ; list; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", list->value );
    }
}

void insert_array( Node **list, int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Node *current = malloc( sizeof( *current ) );
        current->value = a[i];
        current->next = *list;
        *list = current;
        list = &( *list )->next;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 9, 9, 5, 5, 3, 3 };
    int b[] = { 10, 10, 6, 6, 1, 1 };

    Node *list1 = NULL;
    Node *list2 = NULL;

    insert_array( &list1, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    insert_array( &list2, b, sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b ) );

    display( list1 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    display( list2 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    Node *mergelist = merge( list1, list2 );

    display( mergelist );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 9 5 5 3 3 
10 10 6 6 1 1 
1 1 3 3 5 5 6 6 9 9 10 10
```

You have to insert each node in the beginning of the merged list.

Also it would be better to declare the function like

```
Node * merge( Node **list1, Node **list2 );
```

and inside the function before exit to set `*list1` and `*list2` to `NULL` because after executing the function neither `list1` nor `list2` are valid.

Comment: @Rabbid76 In this case one loop is not enough.:)